# Not storing operators in calculator application

Tags: c#, windows

I find this a bit odd. My code works in situations when the operators are not changed, such as 2*2*2 gives me 8 but, when I change the operator is does not work - it goes to the last operator. That is, when I hit something such as: 9 * 6 / 4 it stops me at the division, so, it gives me 9 * 6 and when I hit /, the answer 1.5 appears. Is this from operators not being stored? Any advice, as vague or precise, would be appreciated. It is just strange since IF the same operator is used it works...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    string buffer = " ";
    char op;
    double[] operand = new double[2];
    double result;
    int step = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NumberButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;

        buffer += b.Text;
        txtBox.Text = buffer;
    }

    private void Dot(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!buffer.Contains('.'))
        {
            buffer = buffer + ".";
            txtBox.Text = buffer;
        }
    }

    private void Operations(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (sender as Button);
        op = b.Text[0];
        if (buffer.Length == 0)
            operand[step - 1] = result;
        else
            operand[step - 1] = Double.Parse(buffer);
        if (step == 2)
        {
            Result(null, null);
            operand[0] = result;
            step = 2;
        }
        else
        { 
            txtBox.Text = operand[0].ToString();
            step++;
            buffer = "";
        }
    }
    private void Result(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (buffer.Length != 0)
            operand[1] = Double.Parse(buffer);
        switch (op)
        {
            case '+':
                result = operand[0] + operand[1];
                break;
            case '-':
                result = operand[0] - operand[1];
                break;
            case '*':
                result = operand[0] * operand[1];
                break;
            case '/':
                result = operand[0] / operand[1];
                break;
        }
        txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
        step = 1;
        buffer = " ";
    }
    private void Clear(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (buffer.Length == 0)
        {
            step = 1;
            operand[0] = operand[1] = 0.0;
            op = ' ';
            result = 0.0;
        }
        else
            buffer = "";
        txtBox.Text = buffer;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 6/4=1.5. Just fyi ^_^.

Comment: @StefanDenchev so is 9/6 (which I think is more relevant in this case)

Comment: Vague advice is to step through it in the debugger to see what actually happens when you hit `/`.

Comment: @DStanley little too vague :\

Comment: But i do appreciate it.

Comment: Caused by: `if (step == 2)...`, basically you've already set operation to the new value, so it uses that.

Comment: Yea I believe that line is where the problem occurs... Just debating hwo to go about it

Comment: @StefanDenchev Im not getting this to work. Not entirely sure if setting the operation to the new value beforehand is correct

Comment: [Try this](https://gist.github.com/sdenchev/861ac5420e0e6767f8de). Needs reworking and i hit an exception once but not sure what it was about :P. Should generally help get you started though.

Comment: Im looking at it now.

Comment: @StefanDenchev Have you tested this code yet in an application>

Comment: Sure, somewhat :P... It compiles if that's what you mean ^_^...

Comment: lol it does compile. I was getting the same problem still where it messes up at the last operation.

Comment: Then it might be my error, switching to a whole new blank app and trying it now

Comment: Updated. Just make a new forms app, delete the main form, create a new class file called Form1 and paste the code there.

Comment: omg I think it works, I couldnt do what you said, it took me about 25 mins to make a new app and follow your code but I think it works

Comment: There was an issue with handling the same operator being entered several times e.g. 6+6+6 in the previous version, just make `if (c != operatorbuffer && Decimal.TryParse(buffer, out operand))` to `if (Decimal.TryParse(buffer, out operand))` (remove same operator check) if you're not using the latest revision (from 17 minutes ago). You can browse the revisions and see how yours is different. There are some small kinks but you should be able to figure those out.

Comment: Yea and im working out very small details on the calc as well (not being able to divide by 0, etc) and seeing what exactly I did wrong. Never knew a calculator could be so hard. I want to give you best answer but it isn't posted here

Comment: That's because this doesn't answer your question :P.